# 1 message for multiple required_without rules

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have 2 (contact telephone and contact mobile) fields in a form which either A OR B need to be filled.

I'm validating the form using laravel request validation and the `required_without` rule, which looks like this.

```
'contact_telephone' => 'required_without:contact_mobile',
'contact_mobile' => 'required_without:contact_telephone',
```

So with this code it specifies that one of the 2 fields must be filled.

The error is that if I try to submit the form without filling either one in, the error message shows twice.

How would I show the message just once? Or is there a better rule to achieve this instead of `required_without` that i'm missing?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean.  This may just be front end logic where you display a different message if you find an error in both fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After playing around with it, I realised that only 1 of the `required_without` are actually required.

The logic is quite simple, the required validation (whatever one used) only fires for empty fields. If I specify that the contact telephone is required when the mobile is empty like so

```
'contact_telephone' => 'required_without:contact_mobile',
```

Then it will work for all 3 possible options.

1. If I fill out the mobile and not the telephone then the mobile is no longer empty and the telephone field isn't required anymore (Passes validation).
2. If I fill neither out, then the mobile is empty, and the telephone is then required, thus displaying 1 error message (Fails Validation).
3. If I fill out the telephone then it does not worry about the mobile validation as the telephone is not empty anyway (Passes validation).

This means that either one of the 2 fields are required, but it will only display 1 error message and requires 1 rule.

Answer (score 2):

Just an alternative approach that may solve your problem.

Use an array for contact instead of having `contact_phone` and `contact_telephone`, use `contact[telephone]` and `contact[mobile]`.

Then you can use the validation rule of:

```
'contact' => 'required|array|min:1'
```

Your message for contact could then be `You must fill in either the telephone number or the mobile number`.

Comment: Good suggestion, although I would like to avoid changing the names of my fields if possible. I will continue to look and see if I can figure anything out, Thanks!

Comment: turns out you only need to specify 1. Ill write an answer now.